# Parse XML with hpricot, get attributes

Tags: xml, hpricot

My xml:

http://www.google.ru/ig/api?weather=Chelyabinsk

```
<forecast_information>
  <city data="Chelyabinsk, Province of Chelyabinsk"/>
</forecast_information>
```

How to get city data for example? Not inner_html, just attributes like city data, postal code etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) will be a big help when parsing XML. Looks like [hpricot has support for it](http://wiki.github.com/whymirror/hpricot/supported-xpath-expressions), so it's incredibly easy.

The XPath expression to extract the `data` attribute inside a `city` element is as follows:

```
/forecast_information/city/@data
```

The expression says, find the attribute named `data` (that's what the `@` sign means) inside the element named `city`, which is in turn inside the element named `forecast_information`.

Now, the XML you linked on google.ru is more complicated than the example you posted here. To extract the same information from it, use this expression:

```
//city/@data
```

This expression says, find the attribute named `data` inside the element named `city`, no matter where `city` is in the source XML.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer didn't work for me, but the xpath part put me on the right track. This is what I ended up with:

```
doc = Hpricot::XML(xml)
result = doc.at("//city")['data']
```

Here is my full parser in ruby for an xml element like this:

```
  <Response Field1="abc" Field2="123">

  def parse(xml)
    vars = {}
    fields = %w[Field1 Field2 Field3]
    doc = Hpricot::XML(xml)
    for field in fields
      vars[field] = doc.at("//Response")[field]
    end
    return vars
  end
```